# Module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'read_file'

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to open a shape file in geopandas like so:

```
import geopandas as gpd

shp = gpd.read_file("C:\my_file.shp")
```

but this returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-d0665b3cc874>", line 3, in <module>
    shp = gpd.read_file("C:\my_file.shp")

AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'read_file'
```

I also tried to do this:

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame
```

which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-338cbf14bf64>", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame

  File "C:\Users\spotter\Documents\Python_Scripts\geopandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame

ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoSeries'
```

I am using anaconda3-5.0.1 and installed geopandas with `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

EDIT:

I just downloaded anaconda2 and geopandas works fine, so this is related to anaconda3

Comment: Do you have a local module named `geopandas.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not name your file name as geopandas.py. From the traceback of `from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame`, we can know that the file name you are using is geopandas.py and it makes Python import this file rather than the `geopandas` module. Change this file at the following path to other names and it should work.

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame

File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Python_Scripts\geopandas.py", line 1, in <module>

                                            ---------------
```